# What is the proof of entropy property: $H\left(x,y\right)\le H\left(x\right)+H\left(y\right)$ in Shannon's paper?

Tags: entropy, jensen-inequality

In Shannon's 1948 paper titled "A Mathematical Theory of Communication", in the discussion of [the entropy of the joint event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIUPK.png), there is no proof for this inequality (or subadditivity of entropy) 
$$H\left(x,y\right) \le H\left(x\right)+H\left(y\right)$$ in the paper,

however, I found one proof based on Jensen's inequality from this link https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597D/L01.pdf, but I am confused about ***which convex function is used in this proof***, it is said that the convex function is 
$$\log{\frac{1}{x}}$$ 
the below is the proof:

$$H\left(x,y\right)-H\left(x\right)-H\left(y\right)$$
$$=\left(-\sum_{i,j}{p\left(i,j\right)\log{p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)-\left(-\sum_{i,j}{p\left(i,j\right)\log{\sum_{j}\ p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)-\left(-\sum_{i,j}{p\left(i,j\right)\log{\sum_{i}\ p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)$$
$$=\left(-\sum_{i,j}{p\left(i,j\right)\log{p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)-\left(-\sum_{i,j}{p\left(i,j\right)\log{p\left(i\right)}}\right)-\left(-\sum_{i,j}{p\left(i,j\right)\log{p\left(j\right)}}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\left(-\log{p\left(i,j\right)+\log{p\left(i\right)+\log{p\left(j\right)}}}\right)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\left(\log{\frac{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}{p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)\right)$$

Here comes the question:
$\log{\frac{1}{x}}$ is a convex function, Jensen's inequality is applied, $\log{x}$ is a concave function, the reverse of Jensen's inequality is applied. How to figure out that the function of $$\log{\frac{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}{p\left(i,j\right)}}$$
is the function of $$\log{\frac{1}{x}}$$ or $$\log{x}$$?

If let $x=\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}$, then the function of $\log{\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}}$ would be function $\log{x}$

$$\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\left(\log{\frac{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}{p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)\right)\le\log{\left(\sum_{i,j}\frac{p\left(i,j\right)p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}{p\left(i,j\right)}\right)\ }$$
$$=\log{\left(\sum_{i,j}\ p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)\right)}$$
$$=\log{1}=0$$

Then subadditivity of entropy $$H(X,Y)\le H(X)+H(Y)$$ is proven.

If let $x=\frac{p(i,j)}{p(i)p(j)}$ (rather than $x=\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}$), the function of $\log{\frac{p(i)p(j)}{p(i,j)}}$ would be function $\log{\frac{1}{x}}$ then the proof will become

$$\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\left(\log{\frac{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}{p\left(i,j\right)}}\right)\right)$$
$$=\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\left(\log{\frac{1}{\left(\frac{p\left(i,j\right)}{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}\right)}}\right)\right)\geq\log{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\cdot\frac{p\left(i,j\right)}{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}\right)}\right)}$$

then we just get $$H(X,Y)-H(X)-H(Y)\ge\log{\left(\frac{1}{\sum_{i,j}\left(p\left(i,j\right)\cdot\frac{p\left(i,j\right)}{p\left(i\right)p\left(j\right)}\right)}\right)}$$

Then subadditivity of entropy $$H(X,Y)\le H(X)+H(Y)$$ cannot be proven yet.